# Mulitple switches connected to one pull-up resistor vs separate resistor for each

Tags: resistors, switches, parallel

I have 16 SPDT switches to be used as the address inputs to a UM61512A 64Kx8 CMOS static RAM module. I have designed the circuit to have separate 10k pull-up resistors to +5v when each switch is up and a direct to GND connection when the switch is down. As I was getting ready to solder it all up, it seemed redundant to have 16 pull-up resistors. Are there any issues with just using a single pull-up resistor and connecting all of the switches' up connections to it? Maybe connecting groups of four switches each to a single resistor - thereby only using four resistors? Are there any advantages/disadvantages to these methods?[image: parallel switches]

Comment: Why have pullups anyway? Since you switch the address line between pullup and hard ground, you could just switch between hard supply and hard ground directly? Or if you want pullups, you could have the pullups on each address line, but the switch would only short to ground or not. What SRAM module it is? Single pullup could work, but you would have to check how much current the address pin takes, so in reality you might need stronger pullup or many pullups.

Comment: When are the switches going to change position?  When power is applied. or only when things are powered down?

Comment: Switches may be changed position at any time. Typically when power is applied.

Comment: Be aware that the level is undefined during switch transition. You could pick up interference and have multiple transitions on the inputs.

Comment: @Transistor - I was think about that too, hence my comment.  My concern would be leaving the input floating during the switch transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problems i can think of are

1: if the pins being pulled up draw a significant amount of current then your voltage can drop when there are many connected to the pull-up, to determine the voltage drop just do
`n*I*R`
where n is the number of pins (always keep the worst case scenario in mind) I is the current per pin and R is the pull-up resistor values. If the voltage drops too much maybe you can put a smaller resistor

2: Switching a switch (no pun intended) may generate a transient on the line. this is easily solved with a decoupling capacitor in parallel.

So as far as you consider this i think you are good.

Comment: I'm looking at the datasheet at http://www.lupinek.com/soubory/um61512.pdf

Comment: I can't seem to decipher how much current each address line will pull when it is active. Would I just be safer to use a lower value resistor? How low would be too low?

Comment: ok, its cmos, and the leakage current is 2uA per pin, so you would get a worst case current of 32uA, meaning a voltage drop of 0.32v in absolute worst case, maybe a 4k7 resistor would do the job nicely

Comment: Look it up at page 3

Comment: Thank you diegogmx. Now I know that "Input Leakage Current" is what I'm looking for. Very useful education so far.

Answer (score 2):

The decision to use a pullup resistor is more to do with the switches than with the input currents for your device. 
Since you are using a CMOS memory, the input currents for both high and low are very very low (2uA max). This means the maximum input current for all sixteen input to Vcc is about 32uA or less. If you used a 1K Ohm  pullup the voltage drop under worst case conditions would be about 32mV .....totally insignificant in defining the high voltage.

It terms of the switch however, there are other concerns.
If the switch is an overcenter break before make, you are safe, but if it's a make before break configuration  (like many small slide switches) there can be problems. Direct use of VCC (without a pullup resistor as suggested in other answers) is not recommended practice, and could short VCC to ground in the worst case. It is NEVER good practice to use VCC or in fact any voltage supply without defined current limiting as a pullup point.

My recommendation: Use a single 1k Ohm pullup to VCC as your common pullup point for all sixteen switches.

Comment: I agree: The resistor offers a protection against make-before-break and bouncing. To nkow the value of the resistor you can multiply its value by the number of pin and imagine what would happen. For example: 16x1K would be equivalent to 16K on each pin when all pins are high.

Answer (score 1):

In your configuration, that should be fine.  If it's CMOS, you may even be able to eliminate the last resistor and connect directly to +5V.  If you leave the resistor in, you should check the worst case bias currents to make sure it can support all the address lines being high simultaneously.

Generally, individual pullups(pulldowns) are required for SPST switches or open-drain outputs where the resistor is required to pull it high(low) enough when the switch is open.  Those couldn't be consolidated like this, but you're using the switch to select between two levels rather than to override the pullup.

Comment: i would never the less leave some resistor at least, if the switch is faulty you could get a short from ground to 5v, i know this would be extremely rare, however given the little value of a resistor i would just place it